# Let $V$ be a complex inner product space and $T$ a self-adjoint linear operator on $V$. Show that $I + iT$ is non-singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The question is:

> Let $V$ be a complex inner product space and $T$ a self-adjoint linear operator on $V$. Show that $I + iT$ is non-singular.

Taking $\Vert(I+iT)v\Vert^2$, I'm able to obtain $$\left\langle v|v\right\rangle + \left\langle TT^*v|v\right\rangle$$ Chegg says that this should get me to $\left\langle v|v\right\rangle + \left\langle v|v\right\rangle = 2\left\langle v|v\right\rangle$.

But this would imply that $T$ is also unitary, which I don't see why it necessarily would be.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $V$ is finite dimensional.

Then $I+iT$ is singular if and only if $-i(I+iT)=T-iI$ is singular, that is $i$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. But as $T$ is self-adjoint, its eigenvalues are real. Indeed, if $Tv=\lambda v$, $v\ne0$, you have
$$
\lambda\langle v,v\rangle=
\langle v,\lambda v\rangle=
\langle v,Tv\rangle=
\langle Tv,v\rangle=
\langle \lambda v,v\rangle=
\bar\lambda\langle v,v\rangle
$$
and, since $\langle v,v\rangle\ne0$ we get $\lambda=\bar\lambda$.

Alternatively, from $(I+iT)v=0$, you get
$$
0=\langle v+iTv,v+iTV\rangle=
\langle v,v\rangle-i\langle Tv,v\rangle+
i\langle v,Tv\rangle+\langle Tv,Tv\rangle=
\langle v,v\rangle+\langle Tv,Tv\rangle
$$
Since $\langle v,v\rangle\ge0$ and $\langle Tv,Tv\rangle\ge0$, we get both are zero, in particular $v=0$.

(Note: I use semilinearity in the first variable, but it would be the same for semilinearity in the second variable.)

Comment: Is the claim true if *V* is not finite dimensional as suggested by Exercise 7 in Section 8.4 of [*Linear Algebra*](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit) by Hoffman and Kunze? If so, why do you assume it, or is there a different proof? If not, would you please provide a counterexample.

Comment: @MauriceP One should first agree about the meaning of nonsingular in the case of infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Call a linear transformation $T$ **non-singular** if $Tv=0$ implies $v=0$ (bottom of page 77 in *Linear Algebra*). In that case, your second proof seems valid to me for an infinite-dimensional inner product space. I would modify your first proof, however, because a self-adjoint operator on an infinite-dimensional inner product space need not have an eigenvalue: Let $(I+iT)v=0$ so that $Tv=iv$. Then $i\langle v,v\rangle=\langle v,iv\rangle=\langle v,Tv\rangle=\langle Tv,v \rangle=\langle iv,v\rangle=-i\langle v,v\rangle$ implies $v=0$. If my logic is invalid, would you please let me know.

Comment: @MauriceP Seems good.

Answer (score 0):

We assume $V$ is finite dimensional.

Suppose that $(I+iT)(x)=0$ we have, $<x+iT(x),x+iT(x)>=<x,x>-i<x,T(x)>+i<T(x),x>+<T(x),T(x)>$ since $T$ is self-adjoint, $<x,T(x)>=<T(x),x>$ we deduce that $<x+iT(x),x+iT(x)>=<x,x>+<T(x),T(x)>$=0. This implies that $<x,x>=0$ and henceforth $Ker T=0$ thus $T$ is invertible.

Comment: That is not what "henceforth" means, perhaps you mean "hence". Also, you should use \langle and \rangle rather than < and >.